# Twig include content and check if already include

Tags: symfony, twig

I have read the changelog of the twig (1.15.0 (2013-12-06))

https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/blob/master/CHANGELOG

```
* added a source function to include the content of a template without rendering it
```

But How can I do it? And what does it do exactly?

there is a function to check if a twig has already been included?

thanks !

Comment: In the current form, your question is way to broad. I recommend to narrowdown the question, by asking for a specific question and adding related code fragments.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I don't understand the difference include and new function 'include without rendering' and how to use... there is a function that check if one template is already include like
`{%if alreadyinclude == false %}
{% include "Acme:Foo:bar.html.twig" %}
{%endif%}`

Answer (score 0):

The changelog refers to Twig's new [include function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/include.html), as opposed to the [include tag](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html).

There's some examples in the documentation (click the links above), and also some usage examples in slide 19-21 of [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/javier.eguiluz/twig-tips-and-tricks/19).

When the changelog says "without rendering it", it means it isn't immediately output to the response stream, which enables you to catch and filter the contents before outputting/printing them.